# How can access Scala JDBC connection in Python Notebook ---Databricks

Tags: python, scala, jdbc, databricks

I have a connection object in Scala cell, which I would like reuse it in Python cell.
Is there alternate to temp table to access this connection.
Databricks

Answer (score 0):

Not really - Python code is executed in the different context, so you can have some data exchange either via SparkSession itself (`.set`/`.get` on the SparkConf, but it works only for primitive data), or by registering the temp view